# Is there a way to export details of all EC2s in an AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am aware there's a `Tag Editor` in AWS Console which allows us to export details of all EC2s in an AWS account.

However that list seems to be missing `ami and operating system` of the EC2.

Is there a way to export details including ami and operating system of each EC2 in an AWS account?

Answer (score 5):

You can use AWS CLI and run the below command to get details of all ec2 instances in your account.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances
```

You can also use filters, if required. Please refer the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html).